# How do I increment a count in dart inside a loop?

Tags: flutter, dart

So there's a Javascript (I know) equivalent piece of code that I wrote that I want to translate over to dart, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting the counter to increment.

Here is the Javascript equivalent:

```js
data.assessments.data.forEach((assessment) => {
        const { responses } = assessment.questionnaires[0];
        responses.forEach((response) => {
          response.value.forEach((moodValue) =>
            moodArr.push({
              value: toMoodMap(moodValue),
              count: (moodValue || 0) + 1, // I know this is crazy. This is what I want to replicate
              createdAt: moment(assessment.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            })
          );
        });
      });
```

the final dataset should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "value": "Sad",
        "count": 2,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Happy",
        "count": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Happy",
        "count": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Tired",
        "count": 4,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Energetic",
        "count": 3,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Happy",
        "count": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Sad",
        "count": 2,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Happy",
        "count": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Happy",
        "count": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Sad",
        "count": 2,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Tired",
        "count": 4,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "value": "Tired",
        "count": 4,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09"
    },
    {
        "value": "Sad",
        "count": 2,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09"
    },
    {
        "value": "Energetic",
        "count": 3,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13"
    },
    {
        "value": "Anxious",
        "count": 5,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13"
    },
    {
        "value": "Tired",
        "count": 4,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-14"
    },
    {
        "value": "Happy",
        "count": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-20"
    }
]
```

while not super ideal, it gets the job done for a grouped bar chart. This time I'm trying to replicate this, but using [charts_flutter](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/grouped)

this is what I tried:

```dart
for (var assessment in assessments) {
          final List<dynamic> responses =
              assessment.questionnaires![0].savedResponses;
          final createdAt = assessment.createdAt as DateTime;

          for (var response in responses) {
            final moodValue = response['value'][0];
            moodData.add(MoodReading(
              value: Mood.mapMood(moodValue),
              count: (response['value'][0] || 0) + 1, // this doesn't work
              dateTime: createdAt,
            ));
          }
        }
```

The errors I get are `error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'bool'.` and `error: The operands of the operator '||' must be assignable to 'bool'.`

Is there any way to match something like that javascript version?

Comment: I don't know what `moodValue` is supposed to be in the original JavaScript code, but I'm guessing you probably want something like `(moodValue ?? 0) + 1` (i.e., if `moodValue` is `null`, use a default value of 0, and then add 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying the increase String value can you try this code

```
for (var assessment in assessments) {
          final List<dynamic> responses =
              assessment.questionnaires![0].savedResponses;
          final createdAt = assessment.createdAt as DateTime;

          for (var response in responses) {
            final moodValue = response['value'][0];
            moodData.add(MoodReading(
              value: Mood.mapMood(moodValue),
              count: (response['count'][0] || 0) + 1, // this doesn't work
              dateTime: createdAt,
            ));
          }
        }
```